# Hypothesis Testing with Chi-Squared: Is Overdispersion a concern?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, overdispersion

Assume an AB test design, with one experimental group, one control group, and an anticipated effect on a conversion rate.

The chi-squared test only takes as input successes/trials for each group. This doesn't consider how much that success rate naturally varies, however that seems relevant in saying if the result is statistically significant or not. Does this mean the distribution has an in-built assumption on variance ie. corrections may be needed for over-dispersion, equivalent to using quasi poisson instead of poisson for count data?

Couldn't find much about it for the chi-squared test online.

Comment: Yes, overdispersion might be a concern. Start with https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347732?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents